# The screen locks as soon as I close the lid of my laptop

Tags: power-management, lock-screen

Whenever I close the lid, there it is the computer is locked. And I don't find any option in the power manager provided by Ubuntu to turn that feature off. Is there a tweak available? There might be one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Gnome Control Center --> `Brightness and Lock` and turn off `Lock` and uncheck require my password.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I need password when waking from suspend, so not checking that box.