# Double lock screen Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, lock-screen

So I've got a brandynew System 76 laptop running Ubuntu 14.04, and if I close the lid, putting it to sleep, and reopen it, I am presented with the very nice new Unity lock screen. However, when I enter my password, and it succeeds, it then presents me with a second lock screen. Where I have to enter my password again, before finally being let into the desktop.

Hash anyone else seen this sort of behavior?

Comment: I've got this too. No solution yet

Comment: Ok. I unchecked "When waking from suspend" and I've got the lock screen once on suspend and normal lock

Answer (score 1):

Your question may have been answered here:
[The screen locks as soon as I close the lid of my laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451540/the-screen-locks-as-soon-as-i-close-the-lid-of-my-laptop)

In this response, Cornelius advises:
Go to Gnome Control Center --> Brightness and Lock and turn off Lock and uncheck require my password.

You probably want to leave "require my password" checked for your purposes, but this may help you with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug that is known in Ubuntu. More information about the bug can be found here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1296270

In version 16.04 LTS, the solution for me was to uninstall with `sudo apt remove gnome-screensaver`